# Insert ... select with enums in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, mariadb, jooq

In MariaDB (MySQL) I can do the following:

```sql
create table T1 (
    t1_field enum('yes', 'no', 'meh')
);

create table T2 (
    t2_field enum('yes', 'no', 'meh')
);

insert into T1 (t1_field) 
values ('yes'), ('meh');

insert into T2 (t2_field)
select t1_field
from T1;
```

Since both enums are the same. If I try to do the last query in jOOQ, it won't work because of incompatible types:

```java
using(t)
    .insertInto(T2, T2.T2_FIELD)
    .select(
        select(
            T1.T1_FIELD
        )
        .from(T1)
    )
    .execute();
```

=> The method select(Select>) in the type InsertValuesStep1 is not applicable for the arguments (SelectJoinStep>)

How do I deal with this? How do I get the enum types to match in jOOQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the two types are the same, structurally, they're not the same nominally. jOOQ doesn't treat MySQL / MariaDB enum types the same if they have the exact same definition. Each enum type is unique.

#### One-shot solution for this particular query

You can, however, work around this issue by coercing one type to the other by using [`Field.coerce(Field)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#coerce-org.jooq.Field-):

```java
using(t)
    .insertInto(T2, T2.T2_FIELD)
    .select(
        select(
            T1.T1_FIELD.coerce(T2.T2_FIELD)
        )
        .from(T1)
    )
    .execute();
```

Type coercion works like casting, except that it has no effect on the actual SQL query being generated. In a way, it works like an unsafe cast in Java.

#### Long-term solution using code generation

If you want the two types to be the same, you would need to use a `Converter` to convert all relevant columns to the same enum type. See:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!